# How to Enable Location Services on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, macbook-pro, geolocation, macos-catalina

When using Chrome, Google Maps can not find my location. It works with Safari and Firefox. I guess it has something to do with I can not add Chrome to `Enable Location Services`.

These are my specs:

- Macbook Pro
- macOS 10.15 (Catalina)
- Chrome Version 77.0.3865.120 (Official Build) (64-bit)

[image: Enable Location Services]

Answer (score 0):

**Chrome > Settings > Advanced > Content Settings > Location**

You can enable it from there.

**EDIT** This seems to be a problem with Catalina. As it has just released, problems like these are expected. This issue should be fixed with updates.

Till then, use Safari instead. Or if you *Need/Want* to use Chrome exclusively, I'd suggest downgrading. You can also try Chrome *Beta/Dev* to see if this issue persists.

Comment: I have tried, but it's dosen't work. Most be something new in Catalina. With Safari and Firefox u get an pop-up to enable it in "Apple settings" se picture above